# Eclipse editor show variable occurrence

Tags: eclipse, editor

In Eclipse Standard Installation the editor marks all occurrences of a variable if you click on it with a cursor.

e.g. Setting the cursor somewhere on the 'foo' Variables it highlights all other foo's too.

> public void printString(String foo){
>          System.out.println(foo);    }

Any ideas where to switch this behavior on again or why the feature doesn't work ?
I know the workaround is 'References->Workspace' but the auto highlighting is much more convenient.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You are asking about the "Toggle Mark Occurrences" the short cut for this is `Alt + Shift + O`

Comment: Or `Alt + Cmd + O` on the Mac. It's the text marker button in the tool bar.

Comment: Is there a possibility to jump to the next occurrence of a marked variable?

Comment: hi mike, it's explained here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019818/eclipse-navigate-to-next-previous-marked-occurrence

Answer (score 6):

You can also enable it from

```
Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Mark Occurrences
```