# Eclipse navigate to next/previous marked occurrence

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse has the Mark Occurrences feature where it highlights all occurrences of a selected variable/method. Is there a way to navigate to next or previous marked occurrence?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

After selecting a piece of text:

- Next occurrence is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>.
- Previous occurrence is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>.

Comment: Works great, I just wish it were in the menus.

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone else who was confused by this answer (as I was): `ctrl+k` does NOT move you to the next occurrence; it moves you to the next occurrence of whatever you last selected.  Now, if you double click on an occurrence then it will have the same effect as "next occurrence", because the occurrence will be the last thing you selected, but if you expect to single click on an occurrence and then `ctrl+k` (as I did) you'll find it doesn't work.

Comment: @machineghost I forgot to thank you for your comment, which lead to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12767327/474189) below.

Comment: Teamwork for the win ;-)  Glad to see you figured out a good workaround (I'll try it myself the next time I'm digging through a pile of occurrences).

Comment: Just to confirm.. Ctrl + K is a search for next string occurrence match navigation but not exactly variable usage navigation.

Comment: To select a variable, use Alt-Shift-UP. After the variable has been selected, you can use Ctrl-K to navigate over them.

Comment: Doesn't quite answer the question. See Marian's answer below.

Answer (score 80):

To skip between highlighted occurrences *only*, try the following:

- Above the editor Window, select the down arrow next to the next annotation button.

  [image: Button location]
- Adjust the selection so that only "Occurrences" is marked.

Now, when you click on an item to highlight it, you can skip forwards and backwards to other occurrences using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>(comma)</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>(period)</kbd>.

Comment: Best answer! Ctrl+k is how I used to do this. The problem when working with Java is that it does a text-based search instead of visiting ONLY occurrences of the highlighted variable or method. Depending on the name e.g. "i", this may find a lot of uninteresting occurrences e.g. in comments and as part of a different variable name.

Answer (score 21):

If you are looking to navigate through variables / methods defined in the same class, a quicker way to do this would be to select ( highlight ) the variable / method name you want to navigate to and use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to get into the refactoring mode and then use <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

- <kbd>Tab</kbd>          -  takes you to the next occurrence
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>  -  takes you to the previous occurrence

This way will save you from reaching mere text matches ( including those in comments ), as how <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> behaves. So you are taken through **only "valid" occurrences**.

Comment: Best answer for me. The only drawback is that it won't work for identifiers of libraries for which there is no editable source (such as the Java JDK): try to navigate through all occurrences of `String` by this, it won't work.

Comment: Nice workaround for those who know "go to next occurrence" from, for example, Netbeans.

Comment: Greate. It's much better than to use Ctrl+K

Answer (score 5):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd>

and it's quite easy to remember because <kbd>></kbd> <kbd><</kbd> works as arrow pointing in the direction where you navigate.

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. Ctrl+k repeats the last Find which is not going to be the word automatically highlighted by eclipse, but the word currently *selected*.

Comment: That's actually ctrl + comma, and ctrl+ period, the difference being you don't press and hold shift and eclipse's default config for these keys is to go to next warning/error.