# Eclipse jump to next/previous marked occurrence

Tags: eclipse

As was [asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4019818/1314743), Eclipse has the nice "mark occurences" feature, which shows all occurences of the selected variable or method.

But I don't know any shortcut for jumping to the next/previous occurence in the editor.
The shortcut ctrl+k is not working, it solely works in conjunction with "incremental find" (ctrl+j).

I'm using Eclipse Indigo. Is there any shortcut or other solution?

**Edit:**
The answers and comments in the question linked above are now pretty exhaustive, I think.
It seems there is no all-in-one solution (at least for Java code editing):

- I cant get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>(period)</kbd> to work, at least in Java code where it finds the next problem. Even rebinding this to a different shortcut does not work.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> does text-based search only. If you want to find all occurrences of the variable `i`, it finds any letter `i` within any identifier and comment.
- Renaming mode using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and then navigating through the occurrences using <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> comes close, but only works for identifiers you can actually rename for that source file. It does not work for library code (esp. JDK) for which no editable source is available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I go to "next occurrence" in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588010/how-do-i-go-to-next-occurrence-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 3):

Try **Ctrl** + **,** and **Ctrl** + **.**

Before that make sure you have checked ***Occurences*** in the small navigation dropdown: [image]

You can change the key from Window -> Preferences -> keys:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It works for me.
You can find if your key bindings have changed by looking under `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys` and look for the command `Find Next`. You will see the binding in the column `Binding` and can also check if it's conflicting with something else in the list titled `Conflicts:` at bottom right corner of the dialog.

Comment: When the cursor is on a member variable with more occurences highlighted and I type Ctrl+K, it simply says "String not found". If I use the search feature (Ctrl+F) to find any substring, Ctrl+K works as expected and finds the next match (however, this is not what I wanted).