# How do I go to "next occurrence" in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse you can turn on "Mark Occurrences", and then it will highlight every occurrence of a given variable in the current scope.  That's great, but I'd really like to move from one such occurrence to the next.

I've found two suggestions on how to do this so far, and neither have worked.  First there was this SO post: [Eclipse navigate to next/previous marked occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019818/eclipse-navigate-to-next-previous-marked-occurrence), which suggested `ctrl+k`.  However, that doesn't work for me: in my Eclipse that key-mapping is bound to "find next", not "next occurrence" (there doesn't even seem to be a "next occurrence" in the Eclipse keybindings, but maybe I'm not calling it by the right name).

Then I found a forum post which suggested clicking on the yellow up arrow in the tool bar and checking occurrences, then using `ctrl+,`.  This would have been sub-optimal if it had worked, because I already use `ctrl+,` to move between errors/warnings, but at least it would have been something ... but it didn't work at all (`ctrl+,` just moved me to the next warning).

So, my question is: how can I move (preferably via keyboard shortcut) from one occurrence to the next in Eclipse?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse navigate to next/previous marked occurrence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019818/eclipse-navigate-to-next-previous-marked-occurrence)

Comment: `ctrl+shift+u` is also quite useful in this situation. Opens the "Show Occurrences" window. You'd still need to use the mouse to click on the occurrences, but I find it better that `ctrl+k` at least

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You didn't mention how exactly `ctrl+k` didn't work for you, but it's what I use in similar circumstances. I put the cursor into or select the word that I'm looking for in the editor and then press `ctrl+k` to move me to the next occurrence. Since the next occurrence gets selected, I can use the same combination to move forward or press `ctrl+shift+k` (Find Previous) to move back. (Sorry if that sounds patronizing, but `ctrl+k` sounds exactly like what you're looking for and I don't know the details of the difficulty you had with it.)

I agree about the other combinations. If I have to take my hand off the keyboard, I may as well use the scrollbar.

Best of luck.

Comment: `ctrl+k` doesn't work for me because it does a "find next" (it takes me to the next "occurrence" of whatever I have in my find dialog, not the next highlighted occurrence).  It sounds like that's not what it's doing for you though, which makes me wonder: when you go to the general>keys preference in your Eclipse, what command does it have bound for `crl+k`?  If I can learn that maybe I can fix my binding (I'm guessing my Aptana plug-ins, once again, did something horrible/stupid to my Eclipse setup).

Comment: @machineghost "Find Next" is bound to `ctrl+k` "when editing text". It's the only action tied to that key combination. I'm using Eclipse v3.7 at the moment. Let me know if you're using something else.

Comment: @machineghost I can reproduce your problem (I tested this at first from a cold start, so I had no previous searches). Select the word before you hit `ctrl+k`. This will apparently clear the previous search that was performed via the Find dialog. It loses some keyboard efficiency, though, which stinks.

Comment: Ah ha!  Thanks for the explanation, now I get it: `ctrl+k` doesn't really take you to "next occurrence", it takes you to "next instance of whatever you last selected'.  Not *quite* as good as a true "next occurrence" action, but it's damn close (I just have to double click the occurrence instead of single-clicking it before I `ctrl+k`).  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Double click + ctrl+k is also how I used to do this. The problem with this when working with Java is that it does a text-based search instead of visiting ONLY occurrences of the highlighted variable or method. Depending on the name e.g. "i", this may find a lot of uninteresting occurrences e.g. in comments and as part of a different variable name. The post linked in the answer by @user2836515 gives a great way of really going to the next annotated occurrence using ctrl+, and ctrl+.

Comment: `ctrl + k` does a literal string search for the selected string and takes you to the next matching string. It has nothing to do with *occurrences* of variables, as it is 100% semantically ignorant.

Comment: In case you've got two variables in your source code, let's say `id` and `gridLayout`, and you want to go to the next occurrence of `id` using `Ctrl + k` you will see that gr**id**Layout ('id' substring) will be also marked which is not the expected behavior here

Answer (score 13):

There are a number of SO posts around this. The one that seems to have the best answer is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12767327/2836515

Summary: Change the "Next / Previous Annotation" option (Up / Down arrow in the toolbar) to include occurrences and then use `CTRL`+`,` or `CTRL`+`.` to find next occurrence.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this to maybe reduce some keystrokes/mouse clicks in selecting the initial word:

1. Put the cursor on the word you're looking for
2. Hit `alt` + `shift` + `up`
3. Hit `ctrl` + `k`

This highlights the current word and then does a find next. It doesn't seem to be case-sensitive, though, but that's a small price to pay.

There are definitely some places it doesn't work, though. Like `class` and `implements` in the following (it highlights the whole class):

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a command "Occurrences in File" that is not bound to any key by default.  You can run it by pressing `Ctrl+3` and then typing `occurr`.
It will put all the current variable in the current file in the Search results.  Now `Ctrl+.` and `Ctrl+,` will navigate through those occurrences, instead of through the warnings/errors list.

In order to go back you would want to clean search results.  It seems this command does not have a key bound either.  It is not even shown as a command in the `Ctrl+3` list.  But you may also just do another search and it will overwrite the previous one results.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CTRL+K` to go to next occurrence and `CTRL+SHIFT+K` to go to previous occurrence.