# How to mark reference usages in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, find-occurrences

How to automatically show the usages of local variables, fields, methods, classes and so on?

Notice: The **mark occurences** function in Eclipse does exactly what I want (see [Eclipse editor show variable occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387579/eclipse-editor-show-variable-occurence)), BUT... It doesn't update when I move the cursor. To update marking of occurences, I must turn off **mark occurences**, and then turn it on again.

Now is there a function which marks the occurences of references and updates it automatically when I move the cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To update marking of occurences, I must turn off mark occurences, and then turn it on again.

You shouldn't have to do this, and the occurrences should update themselves anytime you click on another (variable/field/method/class).

The only instance where occurrences aren't reliably displayed is with the latest Eclipse Juno 4.2.
See [bug 400661](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400661) and [bug 398509](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398509), to be fixed (with [this commit](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/commit/?id=2223c41bef449202fb6017ee8d7a571cf3e5010f)) in KeplerM7 (end of April) or Kepler 4.3 full release (June 2013).

Comment: Ah, it's a bug. In bug 400661, Axel Mueller, had exactly the same problem (turning highlighting off and on) and it's a known problem I see. Thanks for pointing to this bug.